# Why won't Kubuntu load my CD?

Tags: mount, kubuntu, disk, cd

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and Kubuntu hasn't recognised my CD!

Here are the results of a `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes Disk identifier: 0x000c5a81

 Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks      Id     System 
 /dev/sda1   *    2048   964603903   482300928   83  Linux /dev/sda2       964605950   976771071     6082561    5  
Extended Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
 /dev/sda5        964605952   976771071     6082560   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

How am I meant to view it in say, Dolphin?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a verry common problem. You could try installing kubuntu-restricted-extras:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Or check if your user is in the cdrom group by typing    `groups` into the konsole.
Or this could be a bug.